# Parsing Image Path in ImageResizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, imageresizer

I'm resizing an image dynamically thus:

```
ImageJob i = new ImageJob(file, "~/eventimages/<guid>_<filename:A-Za-z0-9>.<ext>", 
    new ResizeSettings("width=200&height=133&format=jpg&crop=auto"));
i.Build();
```

I'm attempting to store the image relative URL in the DB. The `i.FinalPath` property gives me:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Church\eventimages\56b640bff5ba43e8aa161fff775c5f97_scenery.jpg
```

How can I obtain just the image filename - best way to parse this?

Desired string: /eventimages/56b640bff5ba43e8aa161fff775c5f97_scenery.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like below,

```
var sitePath = MapPath(@"~");
var relativePath= i.FinalPath.Replace(sitePath, "~");
```

Comment: Server.MapPath throws: 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Church/eventimages/c285d6fb5ce44ee09d10ffaf04d80875_guitar.jpg' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

Comment: Was not aware of the Page's MapPath method!

Comment: You can also use ImageResizer.Util.PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath() - but it will return a virtual path instead of an app-relative one.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Regular expressions

```
Regex.Match
```

Create you pattern and extract desired value

```
string input = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Church\\eventimages\\56b640bff5ba43e8aa161fff775c5f97_scenery.jpg";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^C:\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\([A-Za-z0-9_]+\\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.jpg)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string path = match.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\\", "/");
}
```

Comment: For some reason stackoverflow remove double \, please change all single \ with doubles

Comment: throws: parsing "^C:\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\[A-Za-z0-9_]+\([A-Za-z0-9_]+\[A-Za-z0-9_]+.jpg)$" - Too many )'s.

Comment: I need an elegant solution that allows for different drive letters

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in a utility method:

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri(i.FinalPath);
Uri uri2 = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/"));
Uri relativeUri = uri2.MakeRelativeUri(uri1);
```

(stolen from someone else... can't remember who, but thanks)